# React - toggleClass on button activate all buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm trying to make navigation menu similiar to the nav menu in reactjs.org
I'm using Header component and navigation which is objects with links and name. I'm adding class onClick using the state but this toggle all buttons.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./index.module.css";
import getNavigation from "../../utils/navigation";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "../../images/europa-logo.png";

const Header = () => {
  const links = getNavigation();
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

  const toggleClass = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
<div>
  <nav className={styles.topnav}>
    <div className={styles.pageWrapper}>
      <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />

      <ul>
        {links.map((l, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <Link
              className={isActive ? "btn-active" : null}
              onClick={toggleClass}
              to={l.link}
              value={l.title}
            >
              {l.title}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}

        <li>
          {" "}
          <div className={styles.social}>
            <a href="https://facebook.com">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                size="2x"
                icon={["fab", "facebook-square"]}
              />{" "}
            </a>

            <a href="mailto:someone@mail.com">
              <FontAwesomeIcon size="2x" icon="envelope" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

The result is all buttons are activated: [image: Nav-menu]

My goal is to activate only the link which is clicked and the first button in nav menu need to be activated by default. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<NavLink>` instead of simple `<Link>`
 is a  special version of the  that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL.

```
<NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Link</NavLink>
```

You can check the docs here:
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md

Comment: Great! Thank you. Exact as I want. The first is active by default. The only problem now is that the first link always stay actived. Now when I press the second third or last link the first still actived. 
I want the class of first element to be removed when I select another link the same as in reactjs.org nav menu

Answer (score 1):

You can define active index and your condition look like this

```
className={activeIndex === i ? "btn-active" : ""}
```

Toggle class function:

```
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  const toggleClass = (i) => {
    setActiveIndex(i);
  };
```

and onClick will look like this

```
onClick={()=>{toggleClass(i);}}
```